# Create multidimensional array using two single array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have two arrays as below.

```
$e which is 
Array
(
    [0] => AL-Alabama
    [1] => AK-Alaska
)

$c which is
Array
(
    [0] => Aerospace: General
    [1] => Agriculture/Forestry/Fish ing/Mining: General
)
```

I want to create a multidimensional array using above two single arrays. I wrote below code, but just not working.

```
$mat1=array(array());    
foreach ($e as $ee);             
         {foreach ($c as $cc);    
         {$mat1[$ee][] = $cc;}}
```

It gives me an output as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [AK-Alaska] => Array
        (
            [0] => Agriculture/Forestry/Fish ing/Mining: General
        )

)
```

whereas my ideal output should be an array with combinations stored such

```
(AL-Alabama,Aerospace: General), (AL-Alabama,Agriculture/Forestry/Fish ing/Mining: General) and
(AK-Alaska,Aerospace: General), (AK-Alaska,Agriculture/Forestry/Fish ing/Mining: General)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the thing that $e and $c have in common is the key:
this does mean that $c and $e must have the same length.

```
<?php
$c = ['AL-Alabama', 'AK-Alaska'];
$e = ['Aerospace: General', 'griculture/Forestry/Fish ing/Mining'];
$new = [];

if (count($c) == count($e)) {
    for ($i=0; $i < count($c); $i++) {
        $new[$c[$i]] = $e[$i];
    }
    var_dump($new);
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

**edit:** 
i've changed this

```
$new[$i] = ['e'=>$e[$i], 'c' => $c[$i]];
```

to

```
$new[$c[$i]] = $e[$i];
```

but both work and have an other output

Comment: Thanks. We are getting close, but not yet there. I am getting output as below.   Array
(
    [Aerospace: General] => AL-Alabama
    [Agriculture/Forestry/Fish ing/Mining: General] => AK-Alaska
)
whereas I need;  [Aerospace: General] => AL-Alabama, [Aerospace: General] => AK-Alaska, [Agriculture/Forestry/Fish ing/Mining: General] => AL-Alabama,  [Agriculture/Forestry/Fish ing/Mining: General] => AK-Alaska

Comment: Thanks. You gave me a good direction. I was able to resolve the problem.